# file put content error: no such file in directory

Tags: php, laravel, caching, directory, xampp

I am trying to upload my laravel project from Xampp to shared hosting, but I get the error:

> file_put_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\resido\storage\framework/sessions/Jmmr9HI35UYdhIfZLDTVlLGjCy5AHiuVK9NfOQuT): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

when I try either of the following solutions:

1. delete the file app/bootstrap/cache/config.php
2. composer dump-autoload
3. php artisan config:clear,

the application works. however, all the changes I made while working with xampp is gone and I get the old view from the application template.
how do I fix this problem without losing the changes I made to the project?

I think I'm having this error because the folder C:\xampp\htdocs\resido\storage\framework/sessions does not exist
how do I change this directory to that of the live hosting?

Comment: To clear everything use `php artisan optimize:clear` then `php artisan optimize`

Comment: will this not reset the changes I have made to the website?

Comment: I will clear all cache items like `route`, `config`, `view`, etc. and store newly cache items.

Comment: wow!
that means I have to do all changes and files upload again

Comment: is there no way to change the directory (C:\xampp\htdocs\resido\storage\framework/sessions/FF in the project?

kuz I really don't want to have to do everything from scratch again

Comment: No, I don't mean that. Instead of compiling every code in every time, Laravel uses cache functionality for reuse same compilation code for next time.

Comment: I still do not understand you
what I am asking is: is there no way to change the directory (C:\xampp\htdocs\resido\storage\framework/sessions/FF in the project? kuz I really don't want to have to do everything from scratch again?

Comment: show the code what are you are trying to achieve with  `file_put_contents()`? Or you don't know on which files/lines caused the error?

Comment: Clearing your cache won't change your PHP files/database/routes (application code/data). A cache is just an extra layer that can be added, which will store the results of database queries/routing setup/compiled views etc so that PHP won't need to redo all the heavy lifting on each request. Clearing the cache will keep your application intact. But if the cache is old, then it can show you old results/views/routes instead of using the new code/data. That's why you clear the cache, to make sure you run the new code/views/routes.

Comment: Oh
ok I understand now

you mean I should have cleared the cache before making those changes to the project, right?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the which you are calling is available in the "storage\framework/sessions" folder
OR you can unset all the current sessions from the browser and try

Comment: I do not understand this

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

It is quietly often when we try to move our code to the server by copy paste the whole project.
To solve this problem you need to check inside `storage/framework/sessions`.
Is there a sessions folder available or not, if not then create it manually on the server and give the permission of 664 or 775 to the storage directory recursively.

For permission, you can use this command from server cmd inside the project directory :

`sudo chmod -R 775 storage` and  `sudo chmod -R 775 storage/*`.

Comment: Neither `sudo` nor the permission flags you suggest work on Windows, so I doubt that your answer is related to the given question

Comment: Yes I agreed but in some cases in windows also you need to give permission of private folders.